# how to store in MongoDB in dynamic way without knowing about schema beforehand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql, mongoid

I want to send a very vague and dynamic JSON as a response from a client to server.
for backend I'm using rails + mongoid.

What I know from mongoid is I have to create a model class corresponding to my collection structure so that I can call it from my controller to store data to it this way reminds me traditional RDBMS (still can't figure it out why people are happy with it!!!!)

I don't want to do that , I want to send a JSON (which I don't know about its structure) back to my server and mongoid stores the JSON as it is on the server in other words I don't have any preference structure to storing them and I don't want to have any.

Is there a way to that in rails + mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Mongoid expects you to specify the fields of your model because there is no underlying schema to infer those fields from in the way that ActiveRecord does. But if you just want to store an arbitrary JSON object you can parse it into a Ruby Hash and store it using Mongoid's hash datatype.

```
field :untyped_data, type: Hash
```

There are a few caveats about key names, see http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#fields